# router.get(), use only part of url?

Tags: node.js

Currently I have this code:

```
router.get('/admins', function(res,req) {
```

However, I want it to be when someone goes to say, 'localhost:5000/admins/54323', I want the node-js app to notice 'hey, they're requesting for an admins list! lets find it'. However, with the router.get() function it only works if it is exactly that, is there a way to have it so if **only** the start is /admins then it sets a variable for the final part?

Comment: Kindly post some of your efforts/code then only we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Through more research, I found an answer. I just put /:id after the /admins bit,

you can access the rest of the string in `req.params.id` where .id is the same as the string written after the **:** sign

Comment: Yes it is correct. In your callback function, you will be able to get that value in req.params.id.